# How can I convert a DataTable to an IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>?

Tags: linq, datatable

I'd like to convert a DataTable to an `IEnumerable<>` of `Dictionary<string, object>`.  I tried the following LINQ query,

```
from DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
let rowDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>()
from DataColumn column in row.Table.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
select rowDictionary.Add(column.ColumnName, row[column]).ToArray();
```

but I get the following error:

```
error CS1943: An expression of type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataColumn>' is not 
allowed in a subsequent from clause in a query expression with source type 
'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<AnonymousType#1>'.  Type inference 
failed in the call to 'SelectMany'.
```

I know I can brute-force this with a loop, but it seems like something I should be able to do in LINQ.  Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume that what you want is a Dictionary for each row mapping column to value:

```
var dt = new DataTable();

var columns = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>();
dt.AsEnumerable().Select(dataRow => columns.Select(column => 
                     new { Column = column.ColumnName, Value = dataRow[column] })
                 .ToDictionary(data => data.Column, data => data.Value));
```

Comment: I didn't get the same error as you did, but select must have an object to select and not an action (unless the action returns object). Dictionary.Add returns *void*, therefor it can't be a select argument.

Comment: Why use the `columns.Select` to a new object, and then a `.ToDictionary` on that object, rather than a `.ToDictionary` call directly?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way I do it in the Linq format

```
       var registerdataVerify = (from o in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                  select new
                                  {                                         
                                      DataDef =o["shortName"].ToString(),
                                      Value = Convert.ToInt32(o["valueDec"])
                                  }).ToDictionary(n => n.DataDef, n => n.Value);
```

Answer (score 4):

Why not something simpler since you have linq?

```
var dt = new DataTable();
var columnIndex = 0;
var columnName = "UserID";

var Dict = dt.AsEnumerable().ToDictionary( _
           row => row(columnName), _
           row => row(columnIndex));
```

It becomes even easier if you're working with strongly-typed datasets:

```
var dt = new dsData.UsersDataTable();

var Dict = dt.ToDictionary(dr => dr.UserName, dr => dr.UserID);
```